# How to automatically reference line numbers of a quote?

Tags: cross-referencing, line-numbering

I am trying to find a way to automatically reference the line numbers of a quote that may run on multiple lines.

I am using the `lineno` package to number the lines of a text and it also enables to create line labels `\linelabel{}` and then by using `\ref{}` the corresponding line number is shown. However this only works if the label is attached to a single word, not a sentence that may run on several lines. Is there a command to reference the line numbers of the beginning and the end of a quote?

Answer (score 2):

A possible approach is to set a label to the start and end of the sentence and refer to that. As an extension you can define a command that checks if the starting line number is the same as the ending line number and print a single number if it is and a range otherwise.

The numbers can be extracted from the reference with the `\getrefnumber` command from the `refcount` package, and the test can be performed using `\ifthenelse` from the `ifthen` package.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\linerange}[2]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\getrefnumber{#1}}{\getrefnumber{#2}}}{%
line \ref{#1}%
}{%
lines \ref{#1}--\ref{#2}%
}%
}
\begin{document}
\linenumbers
\begin{quote}
I am using the "lineno" package \linelabel{starta}to number the lines
of a text and it also enables to create line labels \verb+\linelabel{}+
and then by using \verb+\ref{}+ the corresponding line number is
shown\linelabel{enda}. However this only works if the label is attached
to a single word, not a sentence that may run on several lines.
Is there a command to reference the line numbers of the beginning and
\linelabel{startb}the end\linelabel{endb} of a quote?
\end{quote}
See lines \ref{starta}, \ref{enda} and \ref{startb}, \ref{endb}.\\
See \linerange{starta}{enda} and \linerange{startb}{endb}.
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]